# See what my workers have done by dates

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I want to see closed tasks of my workers in Trello by date. Like in calendar view but only closed tasks. Every card must be placed on the date when it was closed.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Report for Trello](http://reportsfortrello.com/) helps achieving what you want.
You can have a timeline report showing you when a card was done and have also a lot of filtering possibility.